# Adding the ability to setup recurring payments in flutter app

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

I am looking at adding the ability for new users to enter payment methods on signup in my flutter app.

I have looked at Stripe and RevenueCat. I have decided to go with RevenueCat because it works better with the Google Play store and the Apple store.

I am looking for a good tutorial on how to add RevenueCat to my flutter app and how to set it up to connect with both Google and Apple.

Does anyone have any good tutorials?
Thanks